# What theorems depend on the unproven Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: number-theory, examples-counterexamples, riemann-hypothesis

I heard that many theorems in modern mathematics depend on the unproven Riemann Hypothesis. What are some examples of such theorems, and what will be the impact on these results if the Riemann Hypothesis is proven to be true?

Comment: Not exactly theorem, but certain probabilistic primality tests such as [Miller-Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants) can be turned into deterministic primality tests with polynomial complexity assuming the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: @TobErnack What would happen to the MR primality test if RH was false?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at this Wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Consequences) for several consequences related to error bounds

Answer (score 1):

The first response [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17209/consequences-of-the-riemann-hypothesis) gives some great answers. Most of which directly relate to the distribution of primes.

Also, there are some interesting consequences of the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis.